# Is there a function to get the current timestamp from mysql database without querying into a table?

Tags: mysql

My webhost server and its mysql database are not synced to the same time. I need the current timestamp from the mysql database. Right now, I have a table that I update a timestamp when I need to get the time. Is there a function that I can get the current timestamp from the mysql database without using a table?

I want to avoid having to store a timestamp, calling to update it and then selecting it everytime I need the current mysql database time.

Comment: the database is called mysql, without any i

Comment: Perhaps a little bit of clarification about the use of this would help shedding some light on the problem. In the meantime I think you could query the database for a timestamp using the a simple `SELECT` statement with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
select now()
```

or

```
select current_timestamp
```

Plenty examples [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: I didn't realize I could use select now() without tables. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There exists 3 different functions which returns needed value.

See [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

---

`NOW()` Return the current date and time at which the SQL statement executes.

It have a lot of aliases: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOCALTIME(), LOCALTIME, LOCALTIMESTAMP, LOCALTIMESTAMP().

---

`SYSDATE()` Return the current date and time at which the function itself executes.

---

`UTC_TIMESTAMP()`   Return the current UTC date and time.

---

All 3 functions have optional argument - fractional part length specificator. Allowed values from 0 to 6 which means the accuracy from a second till a microsecond.